# Yarn tsc shows errors that no longer exist after merge

Tags: reactjs, typescript, repo

I'm running `yarn tsc` on a React app before pushing to our repo. Before this, I merged from master and selected all current changes of my working branch. Before doing this, I had no typescript errors but now it shows typescript errors that don't exist on the working branch (They did exist on the incoming branch). I tried restarting the server and even quitting VSCode. Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any open deleted files?

- I have had this happen before for deleted files open, and in VSCode it would just show a red dot next to a component directory and I had no idea what the issue was.  Turned out a deleted file was still open in my editor, closed it and bam error gone.

Is it showing you where the errors occur, within the file?

- You said you did do the VSCode command pallet command: TypeScript: Restart TS Server.  If not I would run that.

Those are the 2 main things I can think of off the top of my head.  #1 of my list was what caused this for me and it was truly difficult to figure out because I used to never close my tabs in my editor so I didnt see the plain as day error until I started closign them all and saw one labeled (deleted).